# Признаки винительного падежа

Tags: падежи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему в выражении "Число пять — наибольший делитель чисел двадцать и двадцать пять" последние числительные поставлены в винительном (не именительном) падеже?

Answer (score 2):

Это ошибка составителей книги. Достаточно поставить вместо любого из этих чисел такое число, которое имеет в винительном падеже иное окончание, как все будет понятно:

> наибольший делитель чисел тысяча и двадцать пять (НЕ тысячу!)